# Difficulty in Modifying Cell Values in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering an issue with modifying the values of cells in a DataGridView. The DataGridView is bound to a list, and I'm trying to add a new row to this DataGridView and populate it with string values. However, the relevant column contains double values, which is preventing me from achieving this.

I've provided an example in the image below to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

```
var data = _sendDataManager.GetAll(
                    d => d.Readtime > DateTimePickerFirstDate.Value && d.Readtime < DateTimePickerLastDate.Value).Data;

                DataGridViewDatas.DataSource = RadioButtonSortByFirst.Checked ? data
                    : data.OrderByDescending(d => d.Readtime).ToList();
```

Any assistance or guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Your support will contribute to the community as a whole. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Add an object to the source of data instead of trying to add a Row to the DataGridView. Probably better use a BindingList<T> instead of a simple List<T>, if this is what you have there. You should post your code instead of images of a Control

Comment: I have a table in SQL that holds double values, and I'm retrieving it to bind a DataGridView. However, I'd like to add the maximum and minimum values of these numbers along with some string expressions to the last row. Essentially, what I want to do is this. @Jimi

Comment: A bound DataGridView is not a *spreadsheet*, you cannot add arbitrary data. Find other means to show these values

Comment: There must be a way, something like the example I provided in the image, must definitely be achievable.

Comment: Yep, disjoing the data you want to show from its source, representing everything as string (pre-formatting all values). Then you can display anything you want. If it's just for presentation, this may be an option

Comment: maybe that's the only option, thanks.